# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040 with NHibernate, Antlr and Antlr3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

1. I have NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 which requires Antlr 3.1.1
2. I increase the web application performance by minification bundling using  WebGrase which needs Antlr (>= 3.4.1.9004) The performance increased in 38.8% approx. Who wants to learn about it, check these links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification y https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
3. I have both ANtlr Dlls.
4. When I go to a controller that uses NHibernate, I get an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.1.0.39271, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3a9cab8f8d22bfb7' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This error showed up because it is referencing the new library of ANTLR and what I need is travel in the time and use the old library.

5. I tried: binding redirects inside `web.config` without success until now.

Information:

```
 <Reference Include="antlr.runtime, Version=2.7.7.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d7701e059243744f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Antlr.3.1.1\lib\antlr.runtime.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.4.1.9004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Utility, Version=0.1.0.39272, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3a9cab8f8d22bfb7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Antlr.3.1.1\lib\Antlr3.Utility.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\NHibernate.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Some bindings I was trying:

By using NHibernate token

```
 <dependentAssembly>        
        <assemblyIdentity name="antlr.runtime" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" Culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.0.39271" newVersion="3.4.1.9004" />
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>        
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" Culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.0.39271" newVersion="3.4.1.9004" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

By using Antlr token (and traveling in the time)

```
<dependentAssembly>        
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="d7701e059243744f" Culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.4.1.9004" newVersion="3.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I will continue looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I did it! Try to edit the project file (.csproj):

```
 <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.4.1.9004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Before the installation of WebGrease and optimization, It was like this:

```
 <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Antlr.3.1.1\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

So, I traveled to the past. I was modifyng the file **.csproj** and I "restore it". Editing just that library without specify a version, culture, PublicKeyToken and processorArchitecture.

WebGrease and all the optimizations are up and running without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I know that the right answer has been already exist, but maybe it will help someone. This error occurred when I installed `NHibernate` and then installed `FluentNHibernate`. I got `NHibernate 5.0.0` for the first and `NHibernate 4.0.0.4000` for the second. The solution is to firstly delete `FluentNHibernate` and `NHibernate` and reinstall only the `FluentNHibernate` via `NuGet`. I'm not sure should `Antlr3.Runtime` be deleted, but I deleted it manually.

Also I deleted `dependentAssembly` from the `web.config` because I had a layered application.

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

After that all worked fine.